# Create USER in PostgreSQL with default pwd and give privilege to USER to change it on his/her own

Tags: postgresql, change-password

I am looking for options where I can create USER in PostgreSQL with default pwd and give privilege to USER to change it on his/her own once he logs in first time.

I could not find any relevant information in official blogs here:-
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html

Currently used command to create USER is

`CREATE USER rocky with ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'pwd1209';`

Comment: Your command works fine. There is no way in PostgreSQL to *force* a password change.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, from here [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html): " The ENCRYPTED keyword has no effect, but is accepted for backwards compatibility. The method of encryption is determined by the configuration parameter password_encryption. If the presented password string is already in MD5-encrypted or SCRAM-encrypted format, then it is stored as-is regardless of password_encryption ...". It is just noise.